# find closed form of integal $\int \frac{a e^{-i(a-2)x}}{2(a+2)(1+e^{2ix})}dx$, where $a\in R$

Tags: calculus

$$\int \frac{a e^{-i(a-2)x}}{2(a+2)(1+e^{2ix})}dx \text{ and }a\in R$$

Here is what I done:

$$\int \frac{a e^{-i(a-2)x}}{2(a+2)(1+e^{2ix})}dx = \int \frac{a e^{-i(a-2)x}}{2(a+2)} (1+e^{2ix})^{-1}dx = \int \frac{a e^{-i(a-2)x}}{2(a+2)} \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^ke^{2ikx}dx \\= \int \frac{a }{2(a+2)} \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^ke^{(2k-a+2)xi} dx=  \frac{a }{2(a+2)} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \int(-1)^ke^{(2k-a+2)xi}dx \\= \frac{a }{2(a+2)} \sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{1}{(2k-a+2)i} (-1)^ke^{(2k-a+2)xi}dx$$

Then I do not know how to process the summation. Any help I will sincerely appreciate.

Comment: Was thinking of  $$e^{-i(a-1)x}=\cos(a-1)x-i\sin(a-1)x$$  and $$e^{ix}+e^{-ix}=2\cos x$$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee I could not find a close form for the summation use this clue. Could you elaborate it?

Comment: I was thinking creating reduction formula and without the Series expansion/summation.

Comment: @labbhattacharjee that's my fault I will declare the value of $a$ in the problem. If you find the reduction formula for $a$, a integer, please post it and I will really appreciate it.

Comment: It seems that if $a$ is an integer, the integral will turn out to be a $\mathbb C$-linear combination of $\exp (n i x)$, $x^n$, $\log (1 + \exp(\pm 2 i x))$ and $\arctan (\exp(-ix))$ for various $n \in \mathbb Z$.

Answer (score 1):

If $\displaystyle I_a=\int\dfrac{e^{-i(a-2)x}}{1+e^{2ix}}dx$

$$I_a+I_{a-2}=\int\dfrac{e^{-i(a-2)x}(1+e^{2ix})}{1+e^{2ix}}dx=\int e^{-i(a-2)x}\ dx=?$$

Comment: Yes but the initial intergel for $I_w$, where $w \in [-1,1]$, is missing.

Answer (score 1):

$$\int \frac{ae^{i(2-a)x}\text{d}x}{2(a+2)(1+e^{2ix})} = \int \frac{ae^{i(1-a)x}\text{d}x}{4(a+2)\cos{x}}$$

The integral, at first glance from Mathematica, requires the HyperGeometric Function. Perhaps a specific value of a will allow a more elementary form.

Comment: But the key issue is how to reach the hypergeometric form.